# Australian citizen in US for internship - Visa requirements? would ESTA be okay?

Tags: visas, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, australian-citizens

I've been offered an amazing internship for the duration of two months for a NFP in America, but they want me to start in two weeks. Applying for a J1 visa obviously takes longer than that (4-6 weeks according to the embassy).

I am an Australian citizen.

Would the Visa Waiver ESTA be acceptable in this situation?

Comment: Note that VWP and ESTA are not the same thing. ESTA is a system of security checks for visitors to the US; VWP is a system by which visitors from certain countries don't need a visa.

Comment: Your employer should assist you in getting the visa

Answer (score 4):

No, the Visa Waiver Program is not suitable for this purpose.

The rules on permitted activities for the VWP are the same as those for a B1/B2 visa.

[This flyer produced by the CBP](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf) clearly states that an Internship requires a J or H3 visa.

Comment: For Australians, the E-3 visa may also be an option, although it's not a great fit for most interns as it requires you to have a completed degree and a market wage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-3_visa